# socket.io dont work on server and have 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I create a simple socket.io project in my server but I have errors 
my ip that I am work on it is http://5.61.25.90/~socket
on all files are stored in public_html with URL : http://5.61.25.90/~socket/public_html

& here is my codes

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.4/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the above code was the index.html file and in the bottom we have index.js

```
 var app = require('express')();
    var http = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
      });
    });


    http.listen(port, function(){
      console.log('listening on *:' + port);
    });
```

and now I have 404 error in the console panel

like this

**http://5.61.25.90/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LqRzAYF   404 not found           socket.io.js(line 4948)**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this could help:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
```

instead of this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
```

Your app router in the backend is only catching the route `'/'`. So it can't handle requests, that do not match the route exactly.

Comment: on which port is your node server running? If it is not port 80 you need to specify it in the URL like `http://localhost:3000` for port 3000.

Comment: that is ERR_CONNECTION_timedout

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Apache2 virtual hosting on your server. If I'm correct, try adding these two lines to your Apache config file:

```
ProxyPass /socket.io/socket.io.js http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
ProxyPass /socket.io ws://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/
```